# Using Dapper in method context to return multiple lists

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I have a vendor class like this:

```
    public class Vendor: DataAccess
        {
            //properties
            public int VEND_ID;
            public string VEND_NAME { get; set; }
            public string VEND_ADDRESS { get; set; }
            public string VEND_PHONE { get; set; }
            public string VEND_WEBSITE { get; set; }
            public string NOTES { get; set; }

            public static string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
            //Constructors
            public Vendor(string name,string address,string phone,string website,string notes)
            {
                VEND_NAME = name;
                VEND_ADDRESS = address;
                VEND_PHONE = phone;
                VEND_WEBSITE = website;
                NOTES = notes;
            }
            public Vendor(string name)
            {
                VEND_NAME = name;
            }
            public Vendor() { }  
)
```

I have an Orders Class like this:

```
public class Order: DataAccess
{
    //properties
    public int ORDER_ID { get; set; }
    public Vendor VENDOR_ID { get; set; }
    public string ENTRY_DATE { get; set; }
    public string ORDER_NO { get; set; }
    public string TOTAL_COST { get; set; }
    public string STATUS { get; set; }
    public string NOTES { get; set; }
    public string ATTACH_ID { get; set; }
    public static string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    //constructors
    //public Order(string )
}
```

My Data Access Class has the following method:

```
public Tuple<List<Vendor>, List<Order>> GetVendorByName(string name)
{
    using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("TESTDB")))
    {
        using (var multi = connection.QueryMultiple("dbo.GetVendor_ByName", new { VEND_NAME = name }))
        {

            List<Vendor> vd=new List<Vendor>();
            vd.Add(multi.Read<Vendor>().First());
            List<Order> od = new List<Order>();
            od.Add(multi.Read<Order>().Single());
            var output = Tuple.Create(vd, od);
            return output;
        }
        //var output = connection.QueryMultiple<Vendor>("dbo.GetVendor_ByName", new { VEND_NAME = name }).ToList();

    }
}
```

The main class uses it like this:

```
List<Vendor> vendor = new List<Vendor>();
    private void _search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Vendor db = new Vendor(cb_vendor.Text);
        vendor=db.GetVendorByName(cb_vendor.Text);//This is where the error is pointed at
        //dgv_data.Refresh();
        dgv_data.DataSource = vendor;
    }
```

I am trying to get the data from the SQL procedure to show in the DataGridView (dgv_data). There is a one to many relation between Vendor and Order. I want to get all the Orders for whatever Vendor Name is selected
I know the issue is that I am returning List. I tried using Tuples but no joy, it gives me an error about implicit conversions.  Any idea how to do what I am trying to accomplish?

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Tuple,
>   System.Collections.Generic.List>' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'    PurchApp

**Update1:**
The stored procedure is like this:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[GetVendor_ByName]

  (
  @VEND_NAME varchar(100)
  )
  as
  Select Distinct a.VEND_NAME,b.* from dbo.Purch_Vendor a left join purch_order b on a.vendor_id=b.vendor_id  where a.Vend_Name=@VEND_NAME
```

Comment: as the error suggests it cannot implicity imply the type. Specify `db.GetVendorByName(cb_vendor.Text);` to `db.GetVendorByNameTuple<List<Vendor>, List<Order>>(cb_vendor.Text);`

Comment: Why doesn't `Vendor` have a collection property for `Order`s?  Seems like you'd want to add all the orders to the vendor and return it instead of two lists.

Comment: @juharr thats a good point. I added `public Order Ord { get; set; }` to Vendor class. Changed the Method code to `connection.Query<Vendor>("dbo.GetVendor_ByName @VENDOR_NAME", new { VENDOR_NAME = name }).ToList();`. Now I am only seeing an Order column at the end. How do I get the Order properties (all columns because the query returns Vendor Name and then everything about the Orders) to show up as well?

Comment: Is your stored procedure returning 2 recordsets and does the vendor only have one row (based on name) and orders have multiple rows for that vendor?

Comment: @AnilGoel I updated the question with the stored procedure code. It returns multiple rows with same vendor name and the varying orders

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It maps orders to the vendor on name. I have added a property for List of Orders to the Vendor

```
public class Vendor : DataAccess
{
    //properties
    public int VEND_ID;
    public string VEND_NAME { get; set; }
    public string VEND_ADDRESS { get; set; }
    public string VEND_PHONE { get; set; }
    public string VEND_WEBSITE { get; set; }
    public string NOTES { get; set; }
    public List<Order> ORDERS { get; set; }

    public static string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    //Constructors
    public Vendor(string name, string address, string phone, string website, string 
    notes)
    {
        VEND_NAME = name;
        VEND_ADDRESS = address;
        VEND_PHONE = phone;
        VEND_WEBSITE = website;
        NOTES = notes;
    }
    public Vendor(string name)
    {
        VEND_NAME = name;
    }
    public Vendor() { }
}

public class Order : DataAccess
        {
            //properties
            public int ORDER_ID { get; set; }
            public Vendor VENDOR_ID { get; set; }
            public string ENTRY_DATE { get; set; }
            public string ORDER_NO { get; set; }
            public string TOTAL_COST { get; set; }
            public string STATUS { get; set; }
            public string NOTES { get; set; }
            public string ATTACH_ID { get; set; }
            public static string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
            //constructors
            //public Order(string )
        }
 public Vendor GetVendorByName(string name)
        {
            using (IDbConnection connection = new 
              SqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("TESTDB")))
            {
                var dict = new Dictionary<string, Vendor>();

                var vendors = connection.Query<Vendor, Order, Vendor> 
               ("dbo.GetVendor_ByName", (a, b) => Mapper(a, b, dict), new { 
                VEND_NAME = name }, splitOn: "ORDER_ID");

                return dict.Values.FirstOrDefault()

            }
        }

 public Vendor Mapper(Vendor vendor, Order order, Dictionary<string, Vendor> dict)
        {
            if (!dict.ContainsKey(vendor.VEND_NAME))
            {
                vendor.ORDERS = new List<Order>();
                dict.Add(vendor.VEND_NAME, vendor);
            }
            var currentVendor = dict[vendor.VEND_NAME];

            currentVendor.ORDERS.Add(order);

            return currentVendor;
        }
```

Comment: I am getting the error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'PurchApp.Vendor' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<PurchApp.Vendor>` at the same spot. It is called from `Vendor db = new Vendor(cb_vendor.Text);
            vendor=db.GetVendorByName(cb_vendor.Text);
            dgv_data.DataSource = vendor;`

Comment: I saw the update. Its not giving me an error anymore, but the output in the data grid view is only showing the Vendor properties, nothing about the Order.Essentially, its not showing the SELECT fields from the query.